# Show content outside container with overflow hidden and scrollbars

Tags: html, css, layout

https://jsfiddle.net/rafaelfndev/h63r4mye/

Is it possible to show a `tooltip` over a container with `overflow` set to hidden?

I know that is possible using `position: fixed` (green container has property `overflow: hidden`).

I made 2 examples, the problem is when scrolling...first the button scrolls together with the frame, and second, the tooltip scrolls together with the frame.

[image]

I need put these boxes inside the container with `overflow: hidden` and show the tooltip when hovering (however, the tooltips are hidden by the `overflow: hidden` of the container).

[image]

Is it possible do this using only CSS?

Answer (score 0):

**The way to do that is to set it's parent `position="absolute"` not `relative`. so the `tooltip` won't be positioned relative to it's parent and can exceed the container.**

But for your case it will take your design down so i suggest you to do one of these:

easily add a `padding-top: 40px;` to the container so the tooltip can show up at top. and it's better to set a `padding-bottom: 40px;` as well to make it asymmetric.

OR don't put the `tooltip` above the items, put them next to them at left which i also recommend you.